# How can I list all pubnub channels with active subscribers?

Tags: pubnub

I'd like to list all channels associated with a subscribe key that have active subscribers. Is there a way to do that with pubnub? I am using the JavaScript API if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, you can! Please contact us at support@pubnub.com, and we'll get you setup on our 3.6 beta which supports this and other new presence features!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Where Now API

Return a list of channels, associated with a subscribe key, where subscribers exist.

```js
PUBNUB.where_now( { uuid : 'optional-uuid' }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
} );
```

*Note at the time of this posting, `where_now()` is only available in `+3.6` SDK versions.*

Comment: there is also a global `here_now()` method.  however you have to enable this in your account because it is a security vulnerability.  it is disabled by default and recommended to be left disabled.

Comment: Is this information outdated? Trying to call where_now I get a TypeError: pubnub.where_now is not a function.

Comment: where_now() is only available in +3.6 SDK versions.

Comment: This method was hidden because it may cause some concerns with app security.