# How to do pubnub here_now using multiplexing?

Tags: pubnub

Is there a way to multiplex a "here_now" command so I can see the user count in different channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Define pubnub with your `publish_key` and `subscribe_key`

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key: 'demo',
    subscribe_key: 'demo'
});
```

To get occupancy for all channels (Occupants and Occupancy Count)

```
pubnub.here_now({
    callback : function(m){console.log(JSON.stringify(m))}
});
```

To Return a list of channels, associated with a subscribe key, where subscribers exist.

```
pubnub.where_now({
    callback : function(m){console.log(JSON.stringify(m))},
    error : function(m){console.log(JSON.stringify(m))}
});
```

**UPDATE**

To get occupancy info in selected channels. (Something similar to multiplexing)

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key: 'demo',
    subscribe_key: 'demo'
});

var myChannels = ['AAPL', 'SOFIX']; // define your channels here
pubnub.here_now({
    callback : function(m){
        var result = {};
        for (var i=0; i < myChannels.length; i++) {
            if (myChannels[i] in m.channels){
                result[myChannels[i]] = m.channels[myChannels[i]];
            }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

References :

1. here_now : [link](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#here_now)
2. where_now : [link](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#where_now)
3. list all pubnub channels with active subscribers : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914908/how-can-i-list-all-pubnub-channels-with-active-subscribers)

Comment: i tried this and could not get multiplexing to work with it!! (when using multiple channels)

Comment: using `pubnub.here_now` without a 'channel' should return all the channels (and their occupancy) created with that `publish_key` and `subscribe_key`.

Comment: Great answers @Graunier! @kidcapital if you are still having issues, ping us at support@pubnub.com and we'll be happy to assist!

Comment: @Geremy I currently use this pattern and don't like it because it forces me to loop (thus make N number of calls) to the here_now service. Isn't there a way to leverage the multiplexing capability so it only makes one call?

Comment: @kidcapital please ping us at support@pubnub.com and we'll see what we can do to lessen the pain and add this as a feature request. For now, you request all (using global here now), or one, but nothing in the middle.